# How to find a such that X + aY is independent of X-aY for a bivariate distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, covariance, bivariate

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are bivariate normal with equal variance, i.e.
> $[X, Y] \sim \mathcal{N} (0,  \Sigma)$, where
> $$\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}1&\rho\\\rho&1\end{bmatrix}$$ Find $a ≥ 0$
> such that $X + aY$ is independent of $X − aY$

Answer (score 2):

Since they're jointly normal, linear combinations are also. So, we seek for zero covariance between $X+ay$ and $X-ay$:
$$\operatorname{cov}(X-aY,X+aY)=\operatorname{var}(X)-a^2\operatorname{var}(Y)=0$$

Substitute and solve!